# Multiple variables in listboxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok so I am have that my choices in my combobox make different lists in my listbox. What I am trying to do now is make my selection in my listbox give me a variable so that I can calculate something else using the variable.(kind of how I can If SeleceIndex=0 then) I have tried all kinds of things trying to avoid writing more private subs and running them.

I'm using VB.net 2010 and for some weird reason SelectedItem doesn't give me a number. Should I be expected to use a different phrase to find which variable within the listbox the user selected or and I going to have to suck it up and make private subs? 
(i.e. it looks something like this but this is only one variation).

```
intticket = cbx1.SelectedIndex
inttickets = lstbx1.SelectedItem 
If intticket = 0 Then
    SeasonSeats()
ElseIf intticket = 1 Then   
    SingleGameSeats() 
End If  
If (intticket = 0) AndAlso (inttickets = 0) Then   
    intseatgame = intseaboxseats      
ElseIf (intticket = 0) AndAlso (inttickets = 1) Then    
    intseatgame = intsealowerdeck     
End If
```

Comment: This asp.net or winforms?

Comment: Also, .SelectedItem is probably returning an object with properties of Text and Value. Ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx And you might want to pick variable names with more psychological distance instead of intticket and inttickets unless you intended the later to be plural and indicate a collection or the like.

Comment: For WinForm, as far as I know, SelectedItem will only return something if you bind it with a datasource..

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [ListBox.SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx) - this returns the 0-based index of the selected item.

You could also move the second If block inside the first (this is more of a stylistic change):

```
intticket = cbx1.SelectedIndex
inttickets = lstbx1.SelectedIndex

If intticket = 0 Then
    SeasonSeats()
    if (inttickets = 0) Then
        intseatgame = intseaboxseats
    ElseIf (inttickets = 1) Then
        intseatgame = intsealowerdeck
    End If
ElseIf intticket = 1 Then   
    SingleGameSeats() 
End If
```